# Enable EditText underline

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

By Default `EditText` has an underline. I want to start my program with the `Edittext` disabled and when someone clicks on an icon, the `EditText` is enabled.

Here is a picture showing the "to..." `EditText` not having an underline where the others do and the one with focus has it in the Accent color.

[image]

The code I have tried:

```
foodIconButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            foodCurrentEditText.setEnabled(true);
            foodDesiredEditText.setEnabled(true);
            foodDesiredEditText.setFocusable(true);
            foodDesiredEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //foodDesiredEditText.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#03DAC5")));
            //MyDrawableCompat.setColorFilter(foodDesiredEditText.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));

            foodDesiredEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    });
```

The bottom 3 lines of code are the different methods I have tried from suggestions in other questions on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide and show the underline of the `EditText`, you can do it like the following:

To hide the line:

```java
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(foodDesiredEditText, colorStateList);
```

To show the line:

```java
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorAccent));
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(foodDesiredEditText, colorStateList);
```

---

A better solution if you are using `androidx` is:

To hide the line:

```java
foodDesiredEditText.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

To show the line:

```java
foodDesiredEditText.setBackgroundResource(androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_edit_text_material);
```

Comment: holy crap lol you made it look so easy. Thank you so much for putting it into context with my code too. A simple copy and paste lol